# Spark-ML writing custom Model, Transformer

Tags: scala, apache-spark-ml

This is on Spark 2.0.1

I'm trying to compile and use the `SimpleIndexer` example from [here](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/extend-spark-ml-for-your-own-modeltransformer-types).

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.param._
import org.apache.spark.ml.util._
import org.apache.spark.ml._

import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

trait SimpleIndexerParams extends Params {
  final val inputCol= new Param[String](this, "inputCol", "The input column")
  final val outputCol = new Param[String](this, "outputCol", "The output column")
}

class SimpleIndexer(override val uid: String) extends Estimator[SimpleIndexerModel] with SimpleIndexerParams {

  def setInputCol(value: String) = set(inputCol, value)

  def setOutputCol(value: String) = set(outputCol, value)

  def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("simpleindexer"))

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): SimpleIndexer = {
    defaultCopy(extra)
  }

  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
    // Check that the input type is a string
    val idx = schema.fieldIndex($(inputCol))
    val field = schema.fields(idx)
    if (field.dataType != StringType) {
      throw new Exception(s"Input type ${field.dataType} did not match input type StringType")
    }
    // Add the return field
    schema.add(StructField($(outputCol), IntegerType, false))
  }

  override def fit(dataset: Dataset[_]): SimpleIndexerModel = {
    import dataset.sparkSession.implicits._
    val words = dataset.select(dataset($(inputCol)).as[String]).distinct
      .collect()
    new SimpleIndexerModel(uid, words)
 ; }
}

class SimpleIndexerModel(
  override val uid: String, words: Array[String]) extends Model[SimpleIndexerModel] with SimpleIndexerParams {

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): SimpleIndexerModel = {
    defaultCopy(extra)
  }

  private val labelToIndex: Map[String, Double] = words.zipWithIndex.
    map{case (x, y) => (x, y.toDouble)}.toMap

  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
    // Check that the input type is a string
    val idx = schema.fieldIndex($(inputCol))
    val field = schema.fields(idx)
    if (field.dataType != StringType) {
      throw new Exception(s"Input type ${field.dataType} did not match input type StringType")
    }
    // Add the return field
    schema.add(StructField($(outputCol), IntegerType, false))
  }

  override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
    val indexer = udf { label: String => labelToIndex(label) }
    dataset.select(col("*"),
      indexer(dataset($(inputCol)).cast(StringType)).as($(outputCol)))
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error during transformation:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  (10, "hello"),
  (20, "World"),
  (30, "goodbye"),
  (40, "sky")
).toDF("id", "phrase")

val si = new SimpleIndexer().setInputCol("phrase").setOutputCol("phrase_idx").fit(df)

si.transform(df).show(false)

// java.util.NoSuchElementException: Failed to find a default value for inputCol
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out by going into the source code for `CountVectorizer`. Looks like I need to replace `new SimpleIndexerModel(uid, words)` with `copyValues(new SimpleIndexerModel(uid, words).setParent(this))`. So the new `fit` method becomes

```scala
  override def fit(dataset: Dataset[_]): SimpleIndexerModel = {
    import dataset.sparkSession.implicits._
    val words = dataset.select(dataset($(inputCol)).as[String]).distinct
      .collect()
    //new SimpleIndexerModel(uid, words)
    copyValues(new SimpleIndexerModel(uid, words).setParent(this))
  }
```

With this, the params are recognized, and transform happens neatly.

```scala
val si = new SimpleIndexer().setInputCol("phrase").setOutputCol("phrase_idx").fit(df)

si.explainParams
// res3: String =
// inputCol: The input column (current: phrase)
// outputCol: The output column (current: phrase_idx)

si.transform(df).show(false)
// +---+-------+----------+
// |id |phrase |phrase_idx|
// +---+-------+----------+
// |10 |hello  |1.0       |
// |20 |World  |0.0       |
// |30 |goodbye|3.0       |
// |40 |sky    |2.0       |
// +---+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The SimpleIndexer transform method appears to accept a Dataset as the parameter - rather than a DataFrame (which is what you are passing in).

```
case class Phrase(id: Int, phrase:String)
si.transform(df.as[Phrase])....
```

See docs for more info: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/sql-programming-guide.html

EDIT:
The problem appears to be that the SimpleIndexerModel cannot access the "phrase" column via the expression `$(inputCol)`. I think this is because it gets set in the SimpleIndexer class (and the above expression works fine) but is not accessible in SimpleIndexerModel.

One solution is to manually set the col names:

```
indexer(dataset.col("phrase").cast(StringType)).as("phrase_idx"))
```

But it might be nicer to pass in the col names when instantiating the SimpleIndexerModel:

```
class SimpleIndexerModel(override val uid: String, words: Array[String], inputColName: String, outputColName: String)
....

new SimpleIndexerModel(uid, words, $(inputCol), $(outputCol))
```

Results:

```
+---+-------+----------+
|id |phrase |phrase_idx|
+---+-------+----------+
|10 |hello  |1.0       |
|20 |World  |0.0       |
|30 |goodbye|3.0       |
|40 |sky    |2.0       |
+---+-------+----------+
```

Comment: I thought the conversion is implicit. However, even passing a `Dataset` as above yields the same error.

Comment: Ah ok - is it because the inputCol in simpleindexerparams is marked 'final'? Try setting the inputCol value to 'phrase' instead of 'the input column'

Comment: I don't follow. Can you please post your tested solution? FYI the input column is set while instantiating the Indexer `val si = new SimpleIndexer().setInputCol("phrase").set...`

Comment: please mark answer as correct if it solved your problem

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort. The solution you provided does work, but then it sort of deviates from the "recommended approach". For example: see `ConfigurableWordCount` on the [same page](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/extend-spark-ml-for-your-own-modeltransformer-types) where that example does compile and run properly. Only for that reason, I'll up-vote your answer, but not mark it as answered (for now). If I don't find any other way out, I'll come back and mark this as the accepted answer. Thank you.